# MySQL Timestamp Field Not Updating on Form Submission

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, timestamp

I have a Contact Us submission form on my web site (mconchicago.com/Contact_Us).

It is supposed to be set up so that every submission gets an autonumber and a current timestamp. Everyting is working now except the timestamp, which is bringing me to the verge of madness.  Each time it is all zeros.

This is what the records look like when uploaded:

http://www.mconchicago.com/Screenshots/Records.jpg

This is how I have the timestamp field configured:

http://www.mconchicago.com/Screenshots/Structure.jpg

And here is my last attempt at making the PHP work:

```
<?   
$id=$_POST['mysql_insert_id()']; 
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name']; 
$company=$_POST['company'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address=$_POST['address']; 
$city=$_POST['city']; 
$state=$_POST['state'];
$zip=$_POST['zip'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$reason=$_POST['reason'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$timestamp=$_POST['UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'];
mysql_connect("emellis2002.db.9243147.hostedresource.com", "emellis2002", "Newpwd99@") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("emellis2002") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('$id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$company', '$email', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$phone', '$reason', '$comments', 'timestamp')");  
Print "Your information has been received.  Thank you for getting in touch.<br><br>"; 
Print "<a href=http://www.mconchicago.com/Contact_Us.html>CLICK HERE</a> to return to our web site." 
?>
```

You can see from the Structure screenshot that I have tried many different syntax combinations without success, looking at many forum postings in the process.  What am I missing?

Comment: Note that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which is a serious security problem that you should fix by escaping your POST variables using PHP's inbuilt [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function before putting them into the `INSERT` query :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I will read these references.

Comment: No, using HTTPS does not prevent SQL injections. Basically what's happening in your code is that you are taking user input from the POST superglobals and then inserting that input directly into a MySQL query. HTTPS only ensures the security of the connection between your server and the client. It doesn't guarantee that clients won't be sending you bad input - only that all input, good or bad, is sent to you securely without the possibility for anyone to eavesdrop.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the MYSQL DEFAULT_VALUE property.

Edit the table and put CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the DEFAULT_VALUE.

This will insert the current timestamp of the MYSQL Server in the timestamp column everytime there is an insert done in the table.

Comment: I am confused.  Is that not what I have activated?  I checked the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP box in the default column when I set everything up.

Comment: Can you show me the table creation script?
Also if you have already setup CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT_VALUE of the table then you do not need to insert it explicitly. It will be inserted automatically.

Comment: I just tried removing all insertion code from my PHP.  Now when I submit through the contact form no record at all is completed in the database, even though I was given a positive upload confirmation message and no error.  The table was created in pieces.  So would the original creation script still be a valid reference?

Comment: Use this alter command to alter the table - 'ALTER TABLE `<tablename>` CHANGE COLUMN `timestamp` `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;' 
Modify your insert to be as - 
'INSERT INTO `data` VALUES (`$id`, `$first_name`, `$last_name`, `$company`, `$email`, `$address`, `$city`, `$state`, `$zip`, `$phone`, `$reason`, `$comments`);'

Comment: Here is the syntax I am using.  It is being rejected.  What am I doing wrong? 'ALTER TABLE `data` CHANGE COLUMN `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;'

Comment: Three things that I can think of - 1. Does the user with which you have logged in has the rights to modify the table. 2. Was the column's data type timestamp before. 3. Are all the rows NOT NULL?

Comment: The table change went through but the form data is still being discarded without creating a database entry.  I will look into your new comments now.

Comment: Modify your insert query and try. - 'INSERT INTO data (<list all columns separated by commas in the same sequence as the values below but do not mention the timestamp column>) VALUES ($id, $first_name, $last_name, $company, $email, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $reason, $comments);'

Comment: 1.  Yes.  I have changed the table before with this user.  2.  Yes, the column's data type was timestamp before.  3. All of the rows are NULL except for id (auto_increment) and timestamp which are NOT NULL.

Comment: Changed insert query so it now reads: mysql_query('INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ($id, $first_name, $last_name, $company, $email, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $reason, $comments)');  However there is still no record being produced in the database.

Comment: As I said can you try like -  mysql_query('INSERT INTO data (columnnameofid, columnnameoffirstname, columnnameoflastname, ...) VALUES ($id, $first_name, $last_name, $company, $email, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $reason, $comments)');

Comment: Are you saying to try and add a database entry directly to the database, without PHP?

Comment: No. The query I mentioned can be used to enter data from PHP. For example check the last code mentioned [int his link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

```
$timestamp=$_POST['UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'];
```

You're looking in the POSTed values for something called UNIX_TIMESTAMP(). You probably intended:

```
$timestamp = 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()';
```

Also:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('$id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$company', '$email', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$phone', '$reason', '$comments', 'timestamp')");
```

You're trying to insert the string `timestamp` into the field. You probably meant `$timestamp`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I made the two changes you mention above.  But it is still coming up all zeros.

Comment: Just replaced it so that it reads $timestamp= 'NOW()';  But it is still coming up all zeros.

Comment: I see it - change your call to `mysql_query("INSERT INTO \`data\` VALUES ('$id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$company', '$email', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$phone', '$reason', '$comments', $timestamp)");` - you don't want single quotes on the final field

Comment: I just removed the single quotes while retaining $timestamp= "NOW(); At this point no database record at all is created on the back end.  The form data seems to have been discarded although I received no error message.

Comment: You might want to look into printing/echoing mysql_error to see what the database is telling you - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: Thanks for the further guidance.  the error logs are being generated.  The hosting provider is telling me that they could take an hour to become available.

Comment: I have the logs now.  While I was trying to make the timestamp work this error came up over and over again: [Mon May 21 06:01:11 2012] [error] [client 61.135.249.207] File does not exist: /var/chroot/home/content/47/9243147/html/robots.txt.  The provider also said that their timestamp works off some central system.  But the service rep didn't have a lot of details.  I am not familiar with robots.txt.  But from what I've read it is an anti-bot kind of security tool.  Possibly I need the provider's robot.txt file to make the timestamp work on this "central system".  What do you think?